# Looking for LCD replacement (OLED)

Tags: identification, lcd, oled

I'm considering replacing this 16x2 LCD module found in an early '90s E-Mu synthesizer with a modern OLED equivalent.

[image: LCD Module]

However, apart from the Solomon name I can't find *any* reference to any of the markings online anywhere.  The only other identifying marks are "AC358 REV.A QIS 1793" on the 14-pin ribbon cable.

Dimensions wise, the Winstar WEH001602C range (at 85mm x 36mm) appear to be a perfect fit and are supposedly (mostly) compatible with the HD44780, but without the pinout of this board I can't tell how "plug and play" it might be, or indeed if it's even possible.

**FOLLOWUP:**  The WEH001602C was indeed completely compatible with my E-Mu Proteus 1 range of modules and the E-Mu "Vintage Keys" module.  I did find however that it would sometimes fail to initialise when installed in a later Proteus FX model.   It was however slightly thinner so I designed and printed a 3mm thick standoff to bring the display bezel out to the correct position.

Comment: Identify the power lines by studying the PCB, then investigate the remaining as candidate data lines.  There is often some degree of defacto standardization to these things.  A simple USB-based logic analyzer might be useful, or even a scope to figure out what is safe to connect, and then see if it works.  But if the protocol is not compatible you may be stuck using a fast modern MCU to translate on the fly.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks for the suggestion - by continuity testing between the ribbon cable and the pins on the HD44780 I've now confirmed that the pinouts do match, albeit with the connector on the far end of the flying ribbon cable apparently upside down such that pin one is on the bottom row instead of the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, by continuity testing between the ribbon cable and the pins on the HD44780 IC I was able to confirm that the pinouts do match the "standard" pinout for an LCD module.

The Winstar WEH001602C was indeed completely compatible with my E-Mu Proteus 1 range of modules and the E-Mu "Vintage Keys" module. I did find however that it would sometimes fail to initialise when installed in a later Proteus FX model.  The Raystar REC001602C is the same module but with different branding (the two companies are part of the same group).

Physically, the OLED modules are often slightly thinner than the older backlit LCDs so I designed and printed a 3mm thick standoff to bring the display bezel out to the correct position (https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2409650)

p.s. beware the WEH001602D and equivalents - they have the Vss and Vdd pins swapped around compared to the usual convention.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily there is a fair amount of standardization in the pinout of these types of display. Even the 16x1, 16x2, 20x2 and other sizes had the same pinout.

The main difference is whether there are two pins added for the LED backlight at 15 and 16. Usually the other pins are not disturbed though.

It is probably the same as:

[Pololu 16x2 display](https://www.pololu.com/product/772)

Answer (score 0):

HD44780 standardized character lcd driver. That means the  14 pin idc connector is likely using the standard pin out for these type of lcds. Same 5v voltage too.